# Check if key exists in an array and replace its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sockets

**CLIENT CODE**

I am sending an **id** of a client from the client side using

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080?token='+userID);
```

and getting it on the server in my **io.on('connection')
function** using

**SERVER CODE**

```
let token = socket.handshake.query.token;
```

so now I have the **userID** stored in the variable **token**.

Also I am getting the connected **socket id** and storing it like

```
var id = socket.id;
```

Then I am storing the **userID** and the **socketID** in an array as key value pair.

```
var item = {};
item[token] = id;
```

This is an array I am pushing it into(the array is declared outside the on connection function)

```
keyPairArray.push(item);
```

So I am getting an array like this when two people are connected.

```
[ { '10': 'HvlunYNFCcF5vK0-AAAA' },
  { '1456': '17XF7mbh4vYr2WUSAAAB' } ]
```

But when any user reloads the page the array gets like

```
[ { '10': 'HvlunYNFCcF5vK0-AAAA' },
  { '1456': '17XF7mbh4vYr2WUSAAAB' },
  { '1456': 'tIhvkxFbSSAQEckWAAAC' } ]
```

Same **user Id** but different **socket id's**.

The **socket id** changes every time the user reloads the page or opens the page in another tab and the same **UserID** is appended into the array with a different **socket id**.

I don't want to insert the same user again. If the user reloads the page, I want it to check the **userId** which is the key in the array and replace the old **socket id** with the newly generated one.

This is the code that I tried with no luck

```
var checkKeyPair = keyPairArray.some(function(item){
    return item[token] === id;
});

if(checkKeyPair){
    console.log("Hello");
}else{
    keyPairArray.push(item);
    console.log(keyPairArray);
}
```

Comment: You need to have nested search if you want to compare every item with all others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (if ES6 is not a problem):

```js
let token = socket.handshake.query.token;
var id = socket.id;
var item = { [token]: id };
var index = keyPairArray.findIndex(it => Object.keys(it)[0] === token);
if (index === -1) {
    keyPairArray.push(item);
} else {
    keyPairArray[index] = item;
}
```

Comment: Can I put the same code in my `on.disconnect` function and replace `.push` with `.splice` and remove the user object from the array when the user disconnects.

Comment: No, you can't. It will not work if you just replace push with splice

Comment: You have to do: if (index !== -1) { keyPairArray.splice(index, 1); }

Answer (score 2):

You can combine [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to check if there is an user with given userId, something like that:

```js
const users = [{
    '10': 'HvlunYNFCcF5vK0-AAAA'
  },
  {
    '1456': '17XF7mbh4vYr2WUSAAAB'
  }
];

function checkIfUserExists(userId) {
  return users.some((user) => Object.keys(user).indexOf(userId) > -1)
}

console.log(checkIfUserExists('10'));
console.log(checkIfUserExists('11'));
```

Comment: This works. I am getting true when I log it. I can perform operations after that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [{
    '10': 'HvlunYNFCcF5vK0-AAAA'
  },
  {
    '1456': '17XF7mbh4vYr2WUSAAAB'
  }
];



function saveUser(newUserId) {


  users.forEach(function(key) {

    if (Object.keys(key)[0] == newUserId)
      console.log('user exists');
    else {
      var item = {};
      item[newUserId] = 'fsdfsdgdfsgdfhgf55665hftgh56';
      users.push(item);
    }
  });
}

saveUser('1456');
```

Comment: Please explain what you fixed